# Rendering URLs as clickable links

Tags: hyperlinks

Comments in source code often contain URL's.  It would be nice to have these (or links in any plain text context) rendered as clickable links for the convenience factor when navigating a file using the mouse.

**Q:** Is there built-in emacs functionality or a package that automatically render text segments that appear to be URL's as clickable links?

If this doesn't already exist, I'm inclined to implement it as a minor mode using `auto-overlays`.  If you have implementation advice I would appreciate it!

Note:  I'm aware that `browse-url` defaults to the URL at point.

**Edit for clarification:**

I am specifically interested in rendering URL's so that `http://www.google.com` found anywhere within a buffer to which the link rendering behavior has been applied automatically render as

[image: google link rendering example]

It has:

- a distinct underlined link face applied
- a keymap applied to that segment
- a mouse face applied to emphasize that it is clickable
- a 'help-echo value set that decodes url-encoded characters for readability

I only mention `browse-url` for completeness regarding the suggestion that fontifying the link is unnecessary.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Emacs offers `goto-address-mode` for making a number of things, including HTTP links, clickable.

Comment: This is almost precisely what I had in mind (although I will likely use @Tarsius 's [orglink](https://github.com/tarsius/orglink) because it is more powerful).

Answer (score 8):

My [`orglink`](https://github.com/tarsius/orglink) package does that. It "implements support for some Org Mode link types in other major modes.  Links can be opened and edited like in Org Mode".

These are some examples of links that it does and does not support:

```
[[Code]]
[[Code][start of code]]
[[define-derived-mode orglink-mode][orglink-mode]]
<mailto:jonas@bernoul.li>
man:info
<info:man>
https://github.com/tarsius/orglink
TODO support Emacs Lisp xref links like (in) `help-mode'.
TODO support footnote.el links (only)
```

Comment: I was not aware that `orglink` supported a raw URL syntax.  I'll give it a shot! Which of those examples that you list are *not* supported?

Comment: The ones that are prefixed with `TODO`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not 100% clear if you want only the ability to click on URLs,
or if you want to change their faces in the buffer.  For the
former, you can use either `browse-url` as you suggest:

https://www.google.com

```
(global-set-key [mouse-1] #'browse-url) ; pick your preferred mouse button
```

Or, if you just want it to open without having to confirm the URL,
you could use `ffap-at-mouse`:

```
(global-set-key [mouse-1] #'ffap-at-mouse)
```

Here's the docstring for `browse-url`:

> Ask a WWW browser to load URL.
>
> Prompts for a URL, defaulting to the URL at or before point.  Variable
>   `browse-url-browser-function` says which browser to use.
>   If the URL is a mailto: URL, consult `browse-url-mailto-function`
>   first, if that exists.

And here's the docstring for `ffap-at-mouse`:

> Find file or URL guessed from text around mouse click.
>   Interactively, calls `ffap-at-mouse-fallback` if no guess is found.
>   Return value:
>
> - if a guess string is found, return it (after finding it)
> - if the fallback is called, return whatever it returns
> - otherwise, nil

Comment: In response to the clarifying edit of the question: it now looks like you want a lot more than just the ability to click on the URL.  In that case, I think @tarsius's answer is closer to what you want.  I'll leave this one up here in case someone just wants the clickability aspect and wants to know what to bind.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I should have referred to org-mode link behavior originally.  I am intrigued by globally setting `[mouse-1]` though.  I wouldn't have considered that approach.  It does have the advantage(?) of opening file paths which orglink relies on the org link syntax to perform.